# Prove $k$-regular graph with odd number of vertices has $\chi'(G) \geq k+1$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove $k$-regular graph with odd number of vertices has $\chi'(G) \geq k+1$, where $\chi'(G)$ is the edge-coloring number of graph $G$.

Here's what I've done so far:

Let $G=\langle V,E\rangle$ be a $k$-regular graph with $n=2m+1$ vertices. Since the sum of degrees of a graph is even, $kn$ is even, which means $k$ must be even. So  $k=2\ell$ for some $\ell$, so the number of edges for $G$ is $$\frac{kn}2=\frac{2\ell(2m+1)}2=\ell(2m+1)$$

I'm stuck at here, how should I proceed next? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph theory: Prove $k$-regular graph $\#V$ = odd, $\chi'(G)&gt; k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/212073/graph-theory-prove-k-regular-graph-v-odd-chig-k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the number of edge endpoints is $kn$.

If there are $c$ colors, then some color must have at least $kn/c$ edge endpoints.

What is the maximum number of endpoints $M$ a single color can have?  We must have $kn/c \leq M$.  And what happens when $c=k$?